How to determine focal length from a lens specification
I'm working in a ray-tracing program that allows me to construct spherical lenses by specifying the radii of curvature for both faces, the lens radius, and the center thickness. I would like to simulate a lens for which I have a specification, but I'm unsure how to extract the information I need from it. I know from the lensmaker's equation (either thick or thin) that I can find radii of curvature for a lens with a given focal length. So to me, if I can find the focal length of this lens I can find a pair of radii that would give the same focal length. Below is the information I have for the lens.
Key Features:

Provides a 40% wider angle of view
New 9586 Clamp-on mount for easy and quick attachment onto camera
lens
Also available for use with traditional bolt fastening clamp-on ring
(CR95-85)

Specifications:

Class: Broadcast
Effect: 0.6X
Suitable lens: 86 or 85mm O.D. lens
Suitable Focal Length: 2/3": 8.7mm and up
Coating: Multi-coated
Zooming: Fixed focal
Focus: By macro mechanism
Aperture: No light loss
MOD: 0.20m
Format: 2/3" TV
Back mount: 9586 Clamp-on Mount
Construction: 1 group, 1 element
Dimensions: 98mm X 26mm(h)
Net weight: 228g
Finishing color: Black

From reading I've been doing, I found a relationship between angular field of view, sensor size, and focal length: AFOV = 2 * tan^-1(H/2f) (source: Edmund Optics). On the spec sheet it gives a sensor format of 2/3", which I've found measures 8.8mm x 6.6mm, but it doesn't provide an angular field of view value, just that it "provides a 40% wider angle of view", which I take also corresponds with the "Effect: 0.6X" which looks like a magnification to me, but I'm not sure.
How can I extract a focal length from this information?

I don't think you have sufficient information. Why not measure the lens's focus?

@OfekGillon I don't know if I could do that with sufficient precision. I also don't necessarily have access to the physical lens.

So I don't think it's possible

Please clarify what device this specification is for. It does not seem to be for a lens.

@VincentThacker Here's a link to the page I pulled the data from: http://cavision.biz/LWA06X86.aspx
It's clear there's additional data concerning the hardware the physical lens is housed in, but there's still a piece of glass with curved surfaces in there.
